# Rotating words js - how to change the color as well

Tags: jquery, rotation, words

I just found this demo in a different thread, but would like to ask if there is any chance I could change the color of the rotating text as well, I was playing around but couldn't manage to figure it out, any help would be appreciated please

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zqEmT/4/)

```
var keywords = ["awesome", "cool", "fantastic", "incredible"];
var count = 1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $("span.keyword").fadeOut(400, function(){        
        $(this).html(keywords[count]);        
        count++;        
        if(count == keywords.length)            
            count = 0;        
        $(this).fadeIn(400);    
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use another array to hold colours, and apply them using `.css()`

Here's a working version...

http://jsfiddle.net/zqEmT/11/

```
var keywords = ["awesome", "cool", "fantastic", "incredible"];
var colours = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange"];
var count = 1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $("span.keyword").fadeOut(400, function(){        
        $(this).html(keywords[count]).css("color", colours[count]);
        count++;        
        if(count == keywords.length)            
            count = 0;        
        $(this).fadeIn(400);    
    });
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/zqEmT/9/

```
var keywords = ["awesome", "cool", "fantastic", "incredible"];
var count = 1;
setInterval(function(){    
    $("span.keyword").fadeOut(400, function(){        
        $(this).html(keywords[count]);        
        count++;        
        if(count == keywords.length)            
            count = 0;        

        var hue = 'rgb('
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';        

        $(this).fadeIn(400).css('color', hue);    
    });
}, 2000);
```